# Constructing the vector product having in mind that its norm should be an area

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I only saw constructions where we posit the different relations such as $\hat\imath\times\hat\jmath=\hat k$ etc, but I want to do is this.

I want a vector yielding operation $\vec w=\vec u\times\vec v$ that would give me:

1. $\vec w\cdot\vec u=0$
2. $\vec w\cdot\vec v=0$
3. $|\vec w|=|\vec u||\vec v|\sin\left(\angle(\vec u,\vec v)\right)$

So if $\vec w=(a,b,c)$, $\vec u=(d,e,f)$, and $\vec v=(g, h, i)$, I have:

1. $ad+be+cf=0$
2. $ah+bh+ci=0$
3. $a^2+b^2+c^2=(d^2+e^2+f^2)(g^2+h^2+i^2)-(dg+eh+fi)^2$

I squared $(3)$ and got the sine from $\vec u\cdot\vec v$.

What next, though?

Frankly, I don't like to think that we have the norm of the vector product giving us the area of the parallelogram described by both vectors be just a happy coincidence.

Edit:

I can expand $3$ to get $|\vec w|^2=(ei-hf)^2+(di-gf)^2+(dh-eg)^2$, which is literally the norm of the usual vector product, but I haven't at all used $1$ and $2$. It seems too arbitrary to just assume $(a,b,c)=(ei-hf,di-gf,dh-eg)$, especially knowing that I have ordered them in that specific manner because of my prior knowledge of the $\vec w$'s coordinates.

Comment: There are certain assumptions you need to make first.  First the problem of continuity, $\times$ is separately-continuous is probably the least you have to make, $\times$ is bilinear probably is a sledgehammer here.  Second is the question of orientation.  Without these you cannot get the usual vector product.

Comment: Orientation is the important bit that forces the cross product to be what it is (in which case continuity and bilinearity should follow somehow). If $\varepsilon:\Bbb R^3\times\Bbb R^3\to\{\pm1\}$ is any function, then $\varepsilon(u,v)(u\times v)$ satisfies the same three axioms as $u\times v$ but $\varepsilon$ is liable to rip apart the continuity and bilinearity.